# WinForm application upgraded to .NET Framework 4 still requires .NET framework 1.1 to be installed on client machine

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, frameworks

We have one legacy .net winform application which we have updated to .net framework 4.0. And now i can see that all assemblies with latest version. But somehow to run this application in production environment requires .NET framework 1.1 to be installed on client machine.

Also checked all referenced assemblies using ILDASM tool and those are also not  using any .NET 1.0 assembly file.

So Is there any way to check why this application still requires .NET Framework 1.1 to be installed?

Comment: [.NET Framework Setup Verification Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx)

Comment: Might be a stupid question but check to see you are not still using .net 1.1 libraries somewhere.

Comment: How do you know you still need .NET 1.1. That is, what is the error message?

Comment: Checked using ILDASM tool and its not using any .net 1.1 libraries.

Comment: john, unable to launch application if .NET Framework 1.1 is not installed..

Comment: Another possibly stupid question, but as well as updating all of the references have you also updated the applications target framework? Also, the main application might not reference any 1.1. libraries but any other referenced libraries might be?

Comment: Are you using any referenced assemblies/third party assemblies? That might still be using it .net 1.1 ?

Comment: yes, updated target framework to .net framework 4.0 and there could be possibility that some class library requires .NET framework 1.1.. Is there any way to check this? I have already checked referenced assemblies using ILDASM tool..

Comment: very odd even if the third party was 1.1, it will run on any newer .net framework, versioning was solved in .net

Comment: My crystal ball says that is it is a .resx file.  Not always easy to see, some resources are encoded in base64.  Doesn't the Call Stack window tell you anything when it goes bang?